# Masonry e Safari dando bug

Tags: jquery, safari

Para o [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) funcionar no safari devo acrescentar algo?

Pois estou com a seguinte situação:

**Imagem 1- Safari NOK apenas uma colunas**

[image: SAFARI - Aprece somente uma coluna]

**Imagem 2- Chrome OK duas colunas**

[image: Chrome - Aparece tudo ok com duas colunas]

**Código para chamar o masonry**

```js
  var $container = $('#container-masonry');
    // initialize
    $container.imagesLoaded( function() {
      $container.masonry({
        columnWidth: 540,
        itemSelector: '.item',
        isFitWidth: true,
        gutter: 60
      });
```

```css
/*.container{ width: 1280px; }*/
  /*#container-masonry{ width: 1200px; }*/
  #container-masonry .item{ width: 540px; }

  .grid-sizer { width: 100% !important; }

  @media screen and (min-width: 720px) {
    /* 10 columns for larger screens */
    .grid-sizer { width: 540px; }
  }
```

Comment: é interessante colocar o codigo que vc usa para ativar o masonry

Comment: tem algum erro no console ?

Comment: @Otto Coloquei o código que uso para chamar ele. No console não esta aparecendo nada REFERENTE a esse arquivo.